# how to get the timestamp of the image extracted using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

How to get the time stamp of the extracted image obtained by using `ffmpeg`? What option is to be passed to the `ffmpeg` command?
The current command that i am using is:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf select='gt(scene\,0.3)' -vsync 0 -an keyframes%03d.jpg
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `python`?

Comment: there is an "info" filter that might help [?]

Answer (score 2):

Extracting frame while scene change and get time for particular frame . May following line might helps:

```
ffmpeg -i image.mp4 -filter:v "select='gt(scene,0.1)',showinfo" -vsync 0 frames%05d.jpg >& output.txt
```

You will get output like: [Parsed_showinfo_1 @ 0x25bf900] n:   0 pts: 119357 pts_time:9.95637 pos:   676702..... You need to extract pts_time for that run following command.

```
grep showinfo ffout | grep pts_time:[0-9.]* -o | grep '[0-9]*\.[0-9]*' -o > timestamps
```

Using above command you will find following:

```
9.95637
9.98974
15.0281
21.8016
28.208
28.4082
```

Answer (score 1):

An option could be to write timestamps directly over each frame, using `drawtext` [video filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1).

On a Windows machine, using Zeranoe ffmpeg package you can type:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf: timecode='00\:00\:00\:00': r=25: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000000@1: fontsize=30" tmp/frame%05d.jpg" -vsync 0 -an keyframes%03d.jpg
```

The command will dump frame timestamps in the lower part of each frame, with seconds resolution.

Please have a look [here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=318&start=20) to get informations how to setup fonts enviroment variables for ffmpeg.

Answer (score 1):

As this question is tagged in python, I would like to add the following solution for Python developers:

```
from subprocess import check_output
import re
pts = str(check_output('ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf select="eq(pict_type\,I)" -an -vsync 0  keyframes%03d.jpg -loglevel debug 2>&1 |findstr select:1  ',shell=True),'utf-8')  #replace findstr with grep on Linux
pts = [float(i) for i in re.findall(r"\bpts:(\d+\.\d)", pts)] # Find pattern that starts with "pts:"
print(pts)
```

Answer (score 0):

A small update to @DeWil's answer (sorry could not comment as I do not have enough reputations).
The below answer gives the appropriate timestamp by matching with the regular expresion for timestamp "t:" not "pts:".

```
from subprocess import check_output
import re
pts = str(check_output('ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf select="eq(pict_type\,I)" -an -vsync 0  keyframes%03d.jpg -loglevel debug 2>&1 |findstr select:1  ',shell=True),'utf-8')  #replace findstr with grep on Linux
pts = [float(i) for i in re.findall(r"\bt:(\d+\.\d)", pts)] # Find pattern that starts with "t:"
print(pts)
```